# I am getting data between a start time and an end time, but what if the end time is null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a parking lot database. I wrote a stored procedure to get all of the empty spots given a specific datetime. My query is as follows:

```
 select Count(ParkingSlotId) as 'Empty Spots'
   from [ParkingLot].[ParkingSlot]
  where ParkingSlotId not in
       (select ParkingSlotId
          from [Transaction].[ParkingTransaction]
         where @searchTime between TimeIn and [TimeOut])
```

This query works fine unless TimeOut is null, meaning the person hasn't left yet. How would I get this data if TimeOut is null?

Comment: Clue: You need an OR clause to cover that scenario (i.e the scenario where the searchtime is after the in time and the out time is null)

Comment: If the assumption is, if TimeOut is null then return records, and don't care about using a overly crazy future date.  You could always do a ISNULL(TimeOut, '2099-01-01').  Otherwise, the answer provided by GMB is the best route.  My suggestion is more of a silly idea that you could use.

Answer (score 3):

When `TiemOut` is null, the condition in the subquery becomes:

```
where  @searchTime between TimeIn and null
```

This will always evaluate as false (nothing less than `null`).

A solution would be to explicitly handle that use case:

```
select Count(ParkingSlotId) as 'Empty Spots' 
from [ParkingLot].[ParkingSlot] 
where ParkingSlotId not in (
    select ParkingSlotId 
    from [Transaction].[ParkingTransaction] 
    where 
        @searchTime >= TimeIn
        and ([TimeOut] is null or @searchTime <= [TimeOut])
)
```